# Explain: echo -e "\e]52;;HelloWorld"

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

I think this is an OSC 52 statement and it will sent `HelloWorld` to the host clipboard if you use a OSC 52 supported terminal like Windows Terminal.

I also know that `-e` will enable interpretation of backslash escapes.

And `\e` is an ESC character.

But what does does `]52` mean, or is it simple a string of "]52"?

And what does `;;` mean? In shell I believe `;` mean something like end of a command/statement. If it is the same thing here then I don't understand where there are two.
You can also use the statement `echo -e "\e]52;c;HelloWorld"` with a `c`, seem to do the same thing, but what will the `c` do?

Tried to find the answers in the [echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) and [bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) manual but didn't succeed

Comment: As a general hint, if something is quoted it is not intended to be shell syntax. Context is everything. If you send this to a file, it is ASCII text. If you send it to an appropriate terminal device, you enter the murky world of terminfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `;` delimit the command (OSC 52, which is `\e]52`), the first, and the second parameter.  In [the XTerm Control Sequences document](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands), the first parameter is called `Pc` while the second parameter is called `Pd`.

> The first, `Pc`, may contain zero or more characters from the
> set `c`, `p`, `q`, `s`, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, and `7`.  It is
> used to construct a list of selection parameters for
> clipboard, primary, secondary, select, or cut-buffers `0`
> through `7` respectively, in the order given.  If the parameter
> is empty, xterm uses `s 0`, to specify the configurable
> primary/clipboard selection and cut-buffer `0`.

The `Pd` parameter is the selection data (base64-encoded).

So `c` means "clipboard".

On macOS, in the iTerm terminal, either of

```bash
echo -e '\e]52;c;SGVsbG9Xb3JsZA==\a'
```

or

```bash
echo -e '\e]52;c;SGVsbG9Xb3JsZA==\e\\'
```

sets the clipboard buffer to the string `HelloWorld` (with no terminating newline character).  The trailing `\e\\` (`ESC \`) or `\a` (the `BEL` character) is how the data is supposed to be terminated, where `\e\\` is what [the ECMA-48 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/) calls "string terminator".

Comment: I assume the 2nd `pd` parameter doesn't have to be base64, It seems the `\e` tells if the data is base64 or not, right?

Comment: @MrCalvin I'm assuming there are differences in implementation. The document I linked to is obviously specific to `xterm` (but seems to be acting as a sort of normative text), and it say "normally this is a string encoded in base64".  If you mean the `\a` (the bell character) instead of `\e`, it is used to end the command, but I assume that this may also differ between implementations somewhat (iTerm+macOS needs the `\a` at the end, and base64 encoding). The `\e` at the start is the escape character and it needs to be there to introduce the command (it's not saying the data is base64 or not).

Comment: @Kusalananda OSC escape sequences begin with `\e]` (0x1B escape, 0x5D closingbracket) and "officially" (ECMA-48) end with ```\e\\``` (0x1B escape, 0x5C backslash). Ending with `\a` (0x07 bell) instead is a nonstandard but widely supported practice, presumably originating from xterm.

Comment: @egmont Thanks, I was a bit confused about what `ST` was in the XTerm document, but I see now that it's ``ESC \``

Comment: @Kusalananda And there's another dimension to this story: The C0 version of OSC and ST are `\e]` and ```\e\\```, respectively. They also may have a C1 version which was traditionally (with 8-bit locales like Latin-1) the single bytes 0x9D and 0x9C, whereas there's no consensus whether in UTF-8 they should still be these single bytes (arguably the worst choice, probably no one does this), or U+009D / U+009C encoded in UTF-8 (e.g. VTE), or not supported at all (e.g. xterm). Probably it's safe to say that due to UTF-8, the C1 format is obsolete and C0 is preferred.